# PHP Keeping a PDO ATTR_PERSISTENT connection alive

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am running an endless PHP Script with PDO Persistent Connection like this:

```
$conn=new PDO(
  'mysql:host=127.0.0.1','user','pass', array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)
);
```

The mySQL `wait_timeout` variable is set to `28800` and I left the script on idle for 12 hours for test purposes; and the connection is dropped automatically so I presume the `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT` attribute is superseded by the system variable `wait_timeout`.

So I was wondering whether theres a setting or another PHP method to keep the connection breathing as long as the PHP script is running and whether or not that would be a good practice.

My plan B would be executing a resource-less mySQL query every 60 minutes to reset the clock.

*OS: 4GB RAM VPS Debian 64 Bit SSD*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you another way to handle such situations. Whenever you need to run a query in your long-lasting script ensure that there is a connnection. Otherwise reconnect.

```
    try {
        echo "Testing connection...\n";
        $old_errlevel = error_reporting(0);
        self::$pdo->query("SELECT 1");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed, reinitializing...\n";
        self::init();
    }
```

You can find the [full class example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26006338/496223).
I also suggest you to explicitly close the connection in your script when you know you will not use it for a long period.

Comment: What an awesome idea!